# Why is it that unrelated properties are also being called multiple times in Winform databinding, and how to fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, properties, inotifypropertychanged

This is my winform code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 129);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 227);
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 283);
        this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
        this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox3.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(579, 412);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private readonly Form1VM _vm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new Form1VM();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindControlsToVM();
    }


    private void BindControl(Control control, string propertyName)
    {
        control.DataBindings.Clear();
        control.DataBindings.Add(nameof(control.Text), _vm, propertyName);
    }
    private void BindControlsToVM()
    {
        BindControl(textBox1, nameof(_vm.Name));
        BindControl(textBox2, nameof(_vm.Surface));
        BindControl(textBox3, nameof(_vm.Surface1));
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And this is my ViewModel ( I try to follow WPF in Winform)

```
public class Form1VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Surface));
        }
    }

    private string _surface;
    public string Surface
    {
        get { return _surface; }
        set
        {
            _surface = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Surface));
        }
    }

    private string _surface1;
    public string Surface1
    {
        get { return _surface1; }
        set
        {
            _surface1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Surface1));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

After the code compiles and runs, put the breakpoint at the `get` accessor at `Name` property. Now try to change either `Surface` or `Surface1` properties at `TextBox` UI, you will find that `Name` property `get` accessor is also being invoked, multiple times even!

There is a performance issue with this kind of calling.

I've no idea why an unrelated property will get invoked when I change other properties, why is this so, and how to prevent it?

Comment: `control.DataBindings.Add(nameof(control.Text), _vm, propertyName);` Did you mean `control.DataBindings.Add(nameof(control.Name), _vm, propertyName);`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla  no I don't .. what makes you think so ?

Comment: My mistake, somehow I thought the first argument is the name of the control but it's the property you bind to. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I think that the best you can do is use a BindingSource as an intermediary between `_vm` and the binding.  You will still get one polling (_get_) of the properties, but it seems to prevent the multiple hits.  I've never fully traced logic, but it is in the way the [PropertyManager](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyManager.cs,b6661ad15bc73e68) directs the _traffic_.   The multiple hits are do to the PM responding to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event and reloading bound properties.

Comment: @TnTinMn, can you write up a proper answer for that?

Answer (score 3):

> I've no idea why an unrelated property will get invoked when I change other properties, why is this so...

For the class `Form1VM`, each property is unrelated to the others and you also implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` to provide change notification, so you would expect that the binding mechanism to be smart enough to only pull values that have posted a change notification.

Unfortunately, this is not the case and the default mechanism pulls all bound properties after it sends a change to the bound item.  The default mechanism does monitor `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event responds pulling all bound values instead of just the changed one.

This is all handled by a [PropertyManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertymanager?view=netframework-4.8) that is maintained by the [BindingContext Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.bindingcontext?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ContainerControl_BindingContext) of the control's [ContainerControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol?view=netframework-4.8).

The observed behavior appears to be the result of the [PropertyManager.OnCurrentChanged Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyManager.cs,c236bacdc0ea205f,references) that calls [BindingManagerBase.PushData](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingMAnagerBase.cs,fa07aa57325c5480,references) that ultimately results in an iteration over the bindings and calling [Binding.PushData](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Binding.cs,379a99fa51d4c88a) where the following code executes and retrieves the underlying data source value.

```
if (IsBinding) {
   dataSourceValue = bindToObject.GetValue();
   object controlValue = FormatObject(dataSourceValue);
   SetPropValue(controlValue);
   modified = false;
}
```

The subject code is declaring the binding such that the above sequence is triggered by the `TextBox.Validating` event.  When the underlying datasource (`_vm`) raises the `PropertyChanged` event, the sequence begins again with the `PropertyManager.OnCurrentChanged` method.

> how to prevent it?

You could create a derived `PropertyManager` class that overrides `OnCurrentChanged` method and code your own behavior.  To get this custom class to be used, you would also need to create a custom BindingContext class to install it.  This is not something that I would recommend if you can accept a single polling of bound properties on changes propagated by the data binding mechanism.  This behavior can be accomplished by using a BindingSource as an intermediary between `_vm` and the binding.

The following shows the changes to the posted code necessary to use a BindingSource.

```
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _vm = new Form1VM();
    bs.DataSource = _vm;
}
```

---

```
private void BindControl(Control control, string propertyName)
{
    control.DataBindings.Clear();
    control.DataBindings.Add(nameof(control.Text), bs, propertyName, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
}
```

Another alternative is for `Form1VM` to implement the [ICurrencyManagerProvider interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.icurrencymanagerprovider?view=netframework-4.8) and provide a custom [CurrencyManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.currencymanager?view=netframework-4.8) implementation similar to the way the BindingSource class does.  This is something that I have never attempted, but I suspect it would be a similar task to deriving a custom PropertyManager.

Comment: Using `BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();`  doesn't seem to work; unrelated properties still get called

Comment: @Graviton, I never claimed it would.  What it does is prevent is the double scanning on each change.